# simple supported Beam deflection question involving two point loads and a UDL

Tags: beam, deflection

so i was given a problem by my mechanical principles teacher to work out the max vertical deflection of a simply supported beam with two point loads one a distance of 5.3 away from A and another 5.9 away from a on a 6m beam.

the point loads are  both 15.7KN and the UDL is 1.2Kn/M

Now ive worked out most of the constants using the double integration method but the main problem im getting is that c1=c3=c5 = a positive number when an online calculator shows me that its meant to be negative.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I calculated the same but I got a different value from yours.
The maximum deflection that I got is .31818 mm at x = 3.25 m
The constant from the double integration method is -23.189.
I checked it with an online calculator and its perfect...
[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]